Extract multiple occurrences of text between given strings in Google sheet
My input text, in a single cell, is the result of user choice selection. It is similar to (so its a string with multiple substrings):
"meal (20$)", "metro (5,5$)"

I would like to extract (to then sum) the prices of each individual choice, to have this output in another cell:
20+5,5

I have been searching around with the FIND and SPLIT function but I only succeeded to extract the first price with it. Another solution I see would be to split the text and use an ArrayFormula for the summation, but for now I do not find how to split with multiple characters.
I am using Google sheet, so I cannot use the TEXTSPLIT Excel function, and no macros.
Thank you for your help!

Please read the tags before posting your question. You are asking an off-topic question. See [help/on-topic].
